# How to upload large SQL Files?

Tags: php, mysql, database, backup

I have a large sql file < 600 MB.

This files is backup for forum and I want to upload it to empty db.

How I can upload it??

I can't use PHPMyAdmin? and I used BigDump and it doesn't insert all tables.

How to do it?? Is there any other way?

Thanks

EDIT : I don't have access to command line, I just have my CPanel

Comment: If you haven't got access to the command line (either by direct ssh or PHP's `exec` capabilities), _and_ you haven't got direct mysql access (`mysql -h hostname`), _and_ the file is to large to import in PHPMyAdmin (which it probably is), upload it somewhere and ask your hoster nicely. I usually would do it for them ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command line. Must be something like:

```
mysql --user=name --password=pw < mysql_db_dump.sql
```

Comment: Please don't put passwords on commandline.  They get saved to a history file, and then your passwords are stored in clear text file.

Comment: Files _can_ be secured, but it would also be visible in `ps` output, which can't be. Using a properly secured (`0600`) file with credentials & using `mysql --defaults-file=/path/to/file` would indeed be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done from the command line like this:

`mysql -hhostname -uusername -ppassword < bigfile.sql`

Make sure you create your database first and that the user has `CREATE TABLE` privileges such as the root user.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql command line

you can see more details in this [link](http://www.velikan.net/import-sql-dump-file-to-mysql-database/)